# getting error once implement razorpay in ionic 3

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic2, ionic3

Access to Script at 'https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout-frame.js' from origin 'https://api.razorpay.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://api.razorpay.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: please anybody help

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS its a server side cors issue. Are you using ionic serve ?

Comment: yes am using ionic serve its working in app not in app am using nodejs as a backend

Comment: either add a valid header or if its a dev environment then install google chrome plugin to fix this (as a work around)

Comment: Nop in browser its working but not in app which is i build

Answer (score 0):

```
Access to Script at 'https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout-frame.js' from origin 'https://api.razorpay.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://api.razorpay.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Actually, this is not an error! it's an exception `checkout-frame.js` is loaded again when a cross-error occurs. 
If you see carefully in the iframe you can find `<script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout-frame.js" crossorigin="" onerror="appendScript(this)"></script>` which loads `checkout-frame.js` on cross-error.
There might be an issue with your `Razorpay` account if you use with any other subscription API's like Zoho, etc. Check with `Razorpay` support.